# Logstash collectd codec gets empty messages from collectd

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, collectd

I am trying to set up logstash with the collectd codec. This is my configuration:

collectd.conf

```
Hostname    "localhost"
LoadPlugin interface
LoadPlugin load
LoadPlugin memory
LoadPlugin network
<Plugin interface>
    Interface "eth0"
    IgnoreSelected false
</Plugin>
<Plugin network>
    <Server "127.0.0.1" >
    </Server>
</Plugin>
```

logstash.conf

```
input {
        udp {
                port => 25826
                buffer_size => 1452
                codec => collectd { }
                type => "collectd"
        }
}
output {
        stdout {}
}
```

but all I get in my logstash output is lots of these:

> 2015-03-05T22:06:35.802+0000 localhost %{message}

I guess collectd must be sending me events, but they are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after more hours than I care to admit to, I figured it out. You must specify a codec for the output, like:

```
output {
    stdout {  codec => json }
}
```

Now everything works fine

Comment: I have setup collectd in my local lab. But there is no index created in my elasticsearch. If possible, please share any link that you have referred to setup this. 
Do you have any time, please check this link and update your suggest ?. That would help me a lot  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088662/collectd-not-pushing-data-to-logstash

Answer (score 1):

You can specify { codec => rubydebug } or { codec => json_lines } as well. It just is that writing it in a plain format will print %{message} for some weird reason.