# Collectd not pushing data to Logstash

Tags: logstash, collectd

my collectd setup is not pushing the logs to Logstash. Not sure what is the problem here.

---

[image]

---

I have run the tcpdump on my collectd server. Even its not sending any request. I think, the problem may be on collectd. Someone have any idea on what is wrong here.

Note : There is no block in server firewall .

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything immediately wrong with your collectd config, but try setting your Server tag to "localhost". That way you'll be sure to bind your server to your local interface.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `"collectd"` to `collectd` in your sixth to last line.